# how to get last n bits by bit-op?

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bit

I want to get last n bit of number, for example:

```
num = 0b111111111
# if I want to get last 8 bits, it will be 0b11111111
# if I want to get last 2 bits, it will be 0b11
```

I thought this can be ok:

```
bits = 1 << n
little = num & (~bits)
```

but this is wrong, if n = 8, it get `0b110111111`

Comment: You can't get right value if haven't fixed length number(`num`), Try : `new_num = bin(int(num))[2:].zfill(32)` for 32 bit numbers(unsigned). Now can play with number : `print new_num[-15:-3] ` equal to `000000111111` (or reverse for positive index)

Answer (score 13):

This one should work:

```
mask = (1 << n) - 1
little = num & mask
```

`1` shifted left by `n` adds `n` zero bits after 1:

```
>>> bin(0b1 << 4)
'0b10000'
```

If you subtract 1 from this, you will have a mask that has `n` last bits set:

```
>>> bin((0b1 << 4) - 1)
'0b1111'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `bits - 1`:

```
>>> num = 0b111111111
>>> n = 8
>>> bits = 1 << n
>>> num & (bits - 1)  # bits - 1 => 0b1111111 because bits is 0b100000000
255
>>> bin(num & (bits - 1))
'0b11111111'
```